# Using pool.map in an api call, calls the api again

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, pool

I am using pool.map in a function which parallely calls a  function on different chunks of dataframe. I am using this in Django API.

From my API call, a call is made to parallelize_df function which creates pool and pool.map. But I have observed that whenever pool.map is called , the API is called again. This is not an issue when dataframe size is small.

Can anyone please help

Code:

```
    def parallelize_df(df, function_name):   

        dataframe_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
        pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        df = pd.concat(pool.map(function_name, dataframe_split))    

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return df
```

```
    def calculate(df_input):
        # do some calculation
        return df
```

Comment: What's your problem? I don't see any recursive call in your code. Also: there is no need to specify `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` the `Pool` already uses that as default. Moreover you can use `with Pool() as pool:` and avoid calling `pool.close()` or `pool.join()` at the end.

Comment: Hi @Bakuriu , parallelize_df is called from Django API function. Whenever the api is called, whenever it reaches pool.map statement , parallelly same API is called again. I am not able to understand why. I tried it on df having different size. Dataframe having records around 30 are not giving any issue. But when I use dataframe with records around 10000, I can see multiple calls to api

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the issue was because of testing using Chrome. I guess when the API request took a lot of time, then Chrome was resending the request. Tried using Postman and I am not able to replicate the issue